# jQuery text not showing properly using fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, fadein, fadeout

I searched for this problem but couldn't find solution that works for me.

I'm trying to do four checkboxes, from which only three can be selected. And when fourth checkbox is selected there is a faded in message, which informs the user about the limit.
This is the part that fades in the text:

```
$('#warning').fadeIn('slow',function() {
        $(this).stop().text("(You can't have more than 3 selected options)");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#warning").fadeOut(300);
        }, 2500);
});
```

I couldn't do it with a delay, so I used setTimeout.
I can't understand why the first time the fourth checkbox is clicked, the message shows uo instantly. What am I doing wrong?

And also is there a way to do it with a delay instead of setTimer?

Here is a link to the whole code: http://jsfiddle.net/e5kns/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to the start of the script:

```
$('#warning').text("(You can't have more than 3 selected options)");
$('#warning').show();
$('#warning').hide();
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! However I can't quite get it why is it working if I show it and then hide it in the beginning?

Comment: I think it's as if the text has to first be loaded before it can fadeIn. This is the easiest way to preload it

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/e5kns/2/

Use fadeTo and set css opacity to 0... like this:

```
$('#warning').text("(You can't have more than 3 selected options)").css('opacity',0).stop().fadeTo('slow', 1).delay(2000).fadeTo('slow', 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how can I make it play the fading in animation only once if I click continuously on the fourth checkbox?

Comment: oh... then you'd have to use setTimeout like you did. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/e5kns/3/