# jQuery - setTimeout function with $(this) in a plugin

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-plugins, plugins, this

My problem is somehow relatid to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442357/jquery-text-not-showing-properly-using-fadein). I'm trying to do a plugin which shows a message and after that fades it out.

Here is the plugin:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.showWarning = function(msg) {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).text(msg).show().hide(); // <-preloads message
        $(this).fadeIn('fast', function() {
            $(this).stop().text(msg);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(this).fadeOut(300);
            }, 2500);
        });
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

and the whole code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/e5kns/6/

The problem is that the message doesn't disappear, so I suppose it has something ti do with **setTimeout**. Maybe $(this) isn't referencing where it should?

**Firebug** gives:

*a.ownerDocument is undefined*

And **Chrome**:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined*

Answer (score 3):

You could

```
$(this).stop().text(msg).delay(2500).fadeOut(300)
```

---

And indeed, `this` isn't referencing anything other than `window`. Because the browser is calling the timeout callback with `this` set to `window`. `this` is only based on how a function is called.

```
setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(300);
}, this), 2500);
```

Would fix that because it generates another function that discards `this` and uses the provided `this` and explicitly `applie`s that to your original function.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! However there is some problem when using `delay`. Why is it not working when it's chained this way. Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/e5kns/8/

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.showWarning = function(msg) {
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).text(msg).show().hide(); // <-preloads message
            $(this).fadeIn('fast', function() {
                $this = $(this);
                $(this).stop().text(msg);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $this.fadeOut(300);
                }, 2500);
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

ps: As @Esailija recommends, dealy and fadeout is better

Comment: Thank you for this alternative solution, it also does the work!